# Implementing a Linear Search

Tags: c, arrays, structure, parameter-passing, linear-search

The question:
**Read up to 6 pairs of names and ages into TWO separate arrays, and use a linear search to locate a target name and to print that person’s age. The two arrays are called names and ages:**

I am getting lots of errors .. I am not sure about passing the arrays into functions..

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#define ASIZE 20
#define RECSIZE 6

struct record {
    char name[ASIZE];
    int age[ASIZE];
};
struct record na[RECSIZE];

int linearSearch(struct record *a, char *find)
{
int x;
for(x=0; x<RECSIZE; x++)
{
//  if(na[x].name==find[x])
if(a->name[x]==find[x])
    {
        return x;
    }
}
return -1;
 }

int main()
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<RECSIZE; i++)
{
printf("Enter name: ");
scanf("%s",na[i].name);
printf("Enter age: ");
scanf("%i",&na[i].age);
}   

printf("Enter the Search name: ");
char temp[ASIZE];
scanf("%s",temp[ASIZE]);


int result;
result=linearSearch(&na, &temp[]);
printf("%i", result);
    return 0;
    }
```

Please help.

The error is in:
    **result=linearSearch(&na, &temp[]);**

Comment: So what would you like us to do?  You don't show any of the errors.  From looking at your code, I would suggest to get a C book or find tutorials on the net, and read it.

Comment: result=linearSearch(&na[].name, &na[].age, &temp[]); gives an error saying : Expected expression before ] token

Comment: 1) `if(na[x].name==find[x])` --> strcmp() 2) `linearSearch()` call messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ASIZE 20
#define RECSIZE 6

struct record {
    char name[ASIZE];
    int age;
};

struct record na[RECSIZE];

int linearSearch(struct record *a, char *find){
    int x;
    for(x=0; x<RECSIZE; x++){
        if(strcmp(a[x].name, find)==0)
            return x;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(){
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<RECSIZE; i++){
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", na[i].name);//No protection when entered past the buffer
        printf("Enter age: ");
        scanf("%i", &na[i].age);
    }

    printf("Enter the Search name: ");
    char temp[ASIZE];
    scanf("%s", temp);

    int result;
    result=linearSearch(na, temp);
    printf("%i", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On my system, the compiler gave me these errors for your exact code.  Just look at the line numbers (should be exactly like yours) and address each error by looking at the error description.  Once you address these, you will be further down the path of understanding your execution flow:

[image]

Comment: i modified my code.. just check the question again.. I have specified the error i get now... Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I can see that by looking at the very first line of my compile messages.  It is telling you that there is a problem with the operands.  In this case you should use `strcmp()` to compare strings, not `==`.  i.e. `if(strcmp(a, b) == 0){...}`  (substitutions for brevity)

Comment: Also, `char temp[ASIZE];` is a string, not an array of strings.  so the strcmp line should look like:   `if(strcmp(na[x].name,find))` and not:  `if(strcmp(na[x].name,find[x]))`